# Django inbuilt template tags are not working

Tags: django, django-templates

This is my html code I have used in a template.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>{{usn}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>USN {{usn}}</h1>
    <h2>Name {{name}}</h2>
        <h3>{{department}}</h3>
        <% if department %>
        <h4>{{department}}</h4>

        <table>

            <ul>
                <% for r in result %>
                <li>{{result}}</li>
                < endfor %>
            </ul>
            <% for r in result %>
            <li>{{result}}</li>
            <!--<tr><td>r[0][2]</td><td>r[0][3]</td><td>r[0][4]</td></tr>-->
            <% endfor %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of, the for loop executing, I find it printing the statement as it is.
[image: Screenshot of output]

I primarily need to loop through the variable, and print its values in the table format. So please help me, regarding how to get the for loop to execute. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your django template syntax is wrong: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#tags

> Tags are surrounded by {% and %}

(not <%  %>)

> Variables are surrounded by {{ and }}

```
<body>
    <h1>USN {{usn}}</h1>
    <h2>Name {{name}}</
    {% if department %}
        <h3>{{department}}</h3>
        <table>
            <ul>
            {% for r in result %}
                <li>{{r}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
         </table>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

You also have an error in your for loop `{% r in result %}`
Since you are itterating over results, you should be showing r: `{{ r }}`

Comment: Is that not what i did {% for r in result %}, for the for tag?

Comment: @SameerAchanta no, it is not.